# How to install ftp and setup with my website

Tags: server, ftp, magento

Please help me to install a FTP server in Ubuntu new version. I am troubling to install it and configure it for my website.

Is there a direct option to install, like a single command to install and configure it for my site?

My website name is https://flowerportal.in/ and I am using Magento.

Comment: vsftp is a great and pretty simple option.
Try searching for guides on how to install and configure it properly
... or hire someone who can if you don't have time for it yourself.

Comment: it's more secure to use sftp via SSH... then you just enable ssh and use the "sftp" option from your ftp client...